# In navbar how to toggle between unoder list elements

Tags: javascript

In this code there is some error, which I could not get it. Js code not working properly, any advice to change it so that it works properly.

[Web link](https://dragonballzs.000webhostapp.com/).

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Main Navigation -->

  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <nav class="main_nav">
    <ul class="d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-start">
    <li class="active">
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  <!-- navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    "use strict";
     var main_menu = $(".main-menu ul.d-flex li ");
  main_menu.on('click', function() {
    main_menu.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Class name is wrong in your js code. 
use `var main_menu = $(".main_nav ul.d-flex li");` in place of `var main_menu = $(".main-menu ul.d-flex li");`

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    "use strict";
     var main_menu = $(".main_nav ul.d-flex li");
  main_menu.on('click', function() {
    
    main_menu.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    
  });
});
```

```css
.active,.active a {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Main Navigation -->

  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <nav class="main_nav">
    <ul class="d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-start">
    <li class="active">
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  <!-- navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```